# How can I call to an image dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call to `pic1` and `pic2` ... `picn` used object named `image`.

`image` object example code.

```
for (var src in images) {
    image[src] = new Image();
    image[src].onload = function () {
        counter++;
    };
    image[src].src = images[src];
}
```

```
image.pic1,image.pic2 ......image.picn
```

image: Object I try to use several way to call the image object:

```
col = 1; image.pic+col: NaN image.'pic'+col: image.'pic'+'1': image.pic+'1': "undefined1" image.[pic+col] image.[pic1]:
```

to run the next code:

```
for(var col = 1; col < n ; col++) {
    CanvasA.drawImage(image.pic1, x, y, 300, 300);
    //CanvasA.drawImage(image.pic2, x, y, 300, 300);
    //...............
    //...............
    //CanvasA.drawImage(image.picn, x, y, 300, 300);
}
```

this is part of the code:

```
for(var squer = 1;squer < 8 ; squer++ ) {
    y = (squer * 100)-100;

    for(var col = 0; col < 14 ; col++) {
        if (map.raw[squer][col+1] == 1) {
            x = ((col+1) * 100)-100;
            CanvasA.drawImage(image.LEAF1, x, y, BACKGROUND.LEAF.w, BACKGROUND.LEAF.h);
            //CanvasA.fillRect(x,y,100,100);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: "images" look to be undefined, I think you meant "image" in your for loop. Where are image and counter defined?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:
"images" should be "image";

try:

```
var counter = 0;

for (var src in image) {
    image[src] = new Image();
    image[src].onload = function () {
        counter++;
    };
    image[src].src = images[src];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

push your newly created images into another array

```
var imageObjects = [];
for (var src in images) {
    image[src] = new Image();
    ...
    imageObjects.push( image[ src ] );
}
```

then

```
for(var col = 1; col < n ; col++){
    for ( var i; i < imageObjects.length; i ++ ){
        CanvasA.drawImage( imageObjects[i], x, y, 300, 300 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
image.["pic" + col]
```

Comment: yes I think like you but it is not working to me `iimage.['LEAF'+col]: <not available>`